# AppleScript library doesn't evaluate property every time it's loaded

Tags: applescript

Imagine two scripts, first.scpt

```
do shell script "echo first > /tmp/shared_info.txt"
property lib : script "MyLibrary"
lib's display_shared_info()
```

and second.scpt

```
do shell script "echo second > /tmp/shared_info.txt"
property lib : script "MyLibrary"
lib's display_shared_info()
```

The library has following code:

```
property shared_info : read file (POSIX file "/tmp/shared_info.txt")
on display_shared_info()
   display notification shared_info
end display_shared_info
```

My reasoning was that, when the running first.scpt and then second.scpt, it would first display "first" and then "second", since each script first overwrites shared_info.txt and then calls on the library to show the content of it.

However, it seems that the Library doesn't evaluate the shared_info property everytime it's loaded into a script?

**What I want to accomplish** is that the Library initialises its properties everytime it is loaded into a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AppleScript property is evaluated at compile time.
To set it at runtime put the code in the handler

```
property shared_info : ""

on display_shared_info()
    set shared_info to read "/tmp/shared_info.txt" -- works also with POSIX path
    display notification shared_info
end display_shared_info
```

to call the handler use

```
do shell script "echo first > /tmp/shared_info.txt"
tell script "MyLibrary" to display_shared_info()
```